# Qt: How to draw a QRect on top of a QGraphicsVideoItem?

Tags: qt

I have a subclass of a QGraphicsObject. In this class, I use a QMediaPlayer with a QGraphicsVideoItem to play a video.  I am trying to draw on top of the video.

```
class MyClass : public QGraphicsObject
{
Q_OBJECT;

public slots:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);

public:
    QGraphicsVideoItem *_movie_item;
    QMediaPlayer *_movie_player;
}
```

In the paint method, I want to draw a red rectangle **on top** of _movie_item.  To try to do this, I call:

```
void MyClass::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    _movie_item->setVisible(true);
    _movie_item->play();
    painter->fillRect(startx, starty, size, size, Qt::red);
}
```

The red rectangle gets drawn in the appropriate place, but it is always underneath the _movie_item.

Is there a way to draw a rectangle on top of the _movie_item without creating another QGraphicsItem, like:

```
QGraphicsRectItem *_rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(_movie_item)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Composition is the right way to do this - put another item on top of the video item.

Comment: Thanks @ddriver for your response.  I tried using various composition modes of QPainter, and I can observe how the different modes work for a painter that uses a QImage as its paint device (painter->drawImage(QRectF(....), myImage)).  However, for a QGraphicsVideoItem, the painter is not used directly for rendering.  The rectangle is still always drawn underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Using `QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent` flag may help.

[From the docs:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum)

> The item is stacked behind its parent. By default, child items are
>   stacked on top of the parent item. But setting this flag, the child
>   will be stacked behind it. This flag is useful for drop shadow effects
>   and for decoration objects that follow the parent item's geometry
>   without drawing on top of it. This flag was introduced in Qt 4.5.

```
_movie_item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent);
```